# How to mount ZWave switch on stone wall - either retrofit in metal box or better?

Tags: electrical, z-wave

I have a light switch in a surface mounted 4" metal box in the basement.  I replaced the switch with a Decora-style Zwave one in the single-device metal cover.  I thought it was worth attempting because the antenna is behind the plastic paddle, exposed to the front, and there are other ZWave devices in the room.   It works intermittently but not acceptably.

I'd like to avoid replacing the entire box with a plastic one: a) because I'm lazy b) because  it's on a rough stone wall in a high traffic location, I'm worried a plastic box might become damaged.

So I'm looking at a 4" single-device PVC mud ring as a compromise.  It would go over the metal box and expand the exposure of the antenna through plastic from just the paddle to the entire 4" face.  It might not work but it costs $2 and is worth a try.  It's very ugly .. metal box, blue plastic cover, white plastic paddle.

Any better ideas?

1. What would be a good short cut without replacing the whole box?
2. If I remove the whole box and "do this right", what is the best way to mount a Z-wave switch on a solid stone wall, in a manner that is to code and looks at least slightly attractive?

Comment: Another option is that some Zwave devices have an external antenna that you could drop out of the box.  Most of the Aeotec ones do, for example: https://www.amazon.com/Aeotec-controller-metering-switches-Compatible/dp/B076BPM21Y

Comment: Give it a try with the mud ring. If it doesn’t improve, go back to metal.

Comment: Also if your current switch is plain Z-wave, try upgrading it to a Z-wave Plus one -- Plus significantly improved the range, which should help it get through metal boxes as well.

Comment: I understand wanting to keep the metal box but this may be impractical for consistent communications. Metal boxes and stucco walls create a faraday cage and block the signal. I have had to convert 1 home to plastic old work boxes. This was a real pain but provided enough signal that worked for that home owner. This was a couple of years back I don’t think the plus model that @nate s mentioned was available. Trying that model prior to other options may make the change much easier.

Comment: So, my switch is already a Plus model.    I took it out of the metal box and let it dangle for a few days and had no problems at all so I've confirmed that the switch isn't faulty and the metal box is the problem.  One of the cables going into the box is armored so I have to keep the metal box.  I guess I'll install a new surface mount PVC box next to it, use the existing box as a junction box and put the switch in the new adjacent plastic box.  I did manage to find a surface-mount PVC box with knockouts.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestions in the comments.  I tried various lazy solutions, in the end I had to do it right.  Nothing else worked.

I moved the existing metal box close to the ceiling, I had to keep it involved because one of the wires coming into it is armored.  I then ran NM cable from there to the ZWave switch location and bought a surface mount PVC handy box for it.  I also moved it a few inches away from its original location which was directly adjacent to another metal box.

That all this stuff is mounted on a stone wall did not make it a fun job, which was part of the reason I tried to take short cuts but they just didn't work.